# How to set custom DropzoneJS progress value?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, dropzone.js

I am using [dropzone-react-component](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component), which is simply a wrapper of DropzoneJS for react.

I added an event that handles uploading like this:

```
addedfile: file => handleFileUpload(file),
```

However, the upload progress bar simply goes up and validates the upload, while I can see that the upload is still taking place.

So my question, is, how am I supposed to set my own value for the upload percentage and make it work with the dropzone's own styling?

This is the React component:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.componentConfig = {
    iconFiletypes: ['.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.pdf'],
    showFiletypeIcon: true,
    postUrl: 'no-url',
  };
  this.eventHandlers = {
    addedfile: file => handleFileUpload(file),
  };
  this.djsConfig = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Déposez un fichier ici ou cliquez pour en choisir un',
    maxFilesize: 200, // MB
    clickable: true, // Lets you click the dropzone
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*,application/pdf',
    renameFileName: this.props.fileRename || 'myFile',
    parallelUploads: 1,
    uploadMultiple: false,
  };
}

render() {
  return (
    <DropzoneComponent
      config={this.componentConfig}
      eventHandlers={this.eventHandlers}
      djsConfig={this.djsConfig}
    />
}
```

And this is the code used to upload the file, which uses the package [Meteor Slingshot](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot):

```
const handleFileUpload = (file) => {
  var uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("myFileUploads");

  uploader.send(file, function (error, downloadUrl) {
    if (error) {
      // Log service detailed response.
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(downloadUrl);
    }
  });

  let computation = Tracker.autorun(() => {
    if (!isNaN(uploader.progress())) {
      console.log(uploader.progress());
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: add all relevant code and a link to the package please

Comment: Edited question to add relevant code.

Comment: so this is a meteor question? the package u linked is using meteor, now react

Comment: The package isn't really meteor specific, it mostly makes vanilla JS calls.

Comment: so the bottom part is server code? also add a link to the react package. there r two dropzone packages for react

Comment: Added link to react-dropzone-component package

Comment: I cloned the package and browsed around a bit. The code is super messy so I would open an issue at the repo. if u do want to give it a go yourself, I would start with the `uploadprogress` key in the `eventHandlers`